# Figuring out how to cast dynamic_array in IDA PRO to some kind of array in C#

Tags: c#, c++, reverse-engineering, ida

I've stumbled upon an issue where I have to cast a specific parameter which is a dynamic_array to some kind of array in C#

Now we're talking about a game here, and I'm using an external modloader called MelonLoader which is helping me get my C# mod injected into it. The game itself is written in Unity (C#) but has been built to C++ (IL2CPP)

I've been fiddling around a little with IDA Pro to figure out which function I needed to hook onto and found this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZlHL.png

You see, the thing is, the parameter which I'm trying to access is defined as a "struct dynamic_array". I've asked one of my friends for help but the only thing he said it was, that it was a "Simple implementation of std::vector".

As I said previously, I already got the hooking down which is shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V33q1.png

I'm getting the IntPtr just fine, but I need help on how to cast this thing to something I can use in C#, whenever there is a class which can do it, or just having to reimplement it myself which I don't know anything of. If I could get guidance on how to figuring out how to reverse engineer that struct it would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use `dynamic` in c#?

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work at all

Comment: Are you able to share some code? That would help us reaching a solution.

Comment: You'll have to find out what a dynamic_array is, what its memory layout is, and then parse the information out of its memory via the pointer in C#. No way we can know what that is. If it would indeed be a std::vector, you'd typically find a first and last element pointer, but this is completely implementation dependent.